# Change all letters except space from a string using Java

Tags: java

I want to change all letters from a string to "-" char except space using Java.

I tried:

```
String out = secretWord.replaceAll("^ " , "-");
```

and

```
String out = secretWord.replaceAll("\\s" , "-");
```

They didn't work.

I tried:

```
String newWord = secretWord.replaceAll("[A-Z]" , "-");
```

It worked but i didn't change Turkish characters I use in that string.

Original Code:

```
public class ChangeToLine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        String originalWord = "ABİDİKUŞ GUBİDİKUŞ";
        String secretWord = originalWord;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the problematic string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `\\S` regex:

```java
String s = "Sonra görüşürüz";
String replaced = s.replaceAll("\\S", "-");
System.out.println(replaced); // outputs ----- ---------
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a character class

```
String out = secretWord.replaceAll("[^ ]" , "-");
```

or a capital `S`, instead of a lower `s` to replace all non space chars

```
String out2 = secretWord.replaceAll("\\S" , "-");
```

Answer (score 0):

NOT needs to be expressed in square brackets in `java.util.regex.Pattern`:

```java
String out = secretWord.replaceAll("[^\\s]", "-")
```